# Amazon instance no longer allowing login with private key

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh

I've been through so many questions on SO like this and none of them have worked, but also I can pinpoint when this happened so I may be able to add another layer of detail.

Most of the solutions indicate that the asker is:

1. using the incorrect key
2. incorrect username.  This is an Ubuntu image and I've tried 'ubuntu', 'ec2-user', and the new username that I created for myself on the machine.  None work; all same error message.

Either instance suggests trying: `ssh -i kename.pem username@host -vvv`, and this is the way that always worked for me in the past.... until I reimaged my client machine.  Ever since then I've gotten the attached ssh trace.

I've tried the second level attempt of creating an AMI from the server I'm locked out of, spinning up a new instance, creating a new key, and trying to log into the new instance.  No luck there.

So, my question is: is there something that could have been on the old machine, possibly my public key or something, that I no longer have and thus cannot connect to any of the instances?  I was under the impression that you only need the private key to authenticate.  I'm pretty thin on SSH protocol aside from logging into machines with it, the trace below doesn't seem to give me any hints as to where this breaks down with the exception of "debug1: Roaming not allowed by server", but maybe that's not relevant and I'm making a bigger deal of it than it is.

I'm hoping the reimaging portion of this question sheds some other light on the subject.

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to **hostname** [**hostname**] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug2: fd 100 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ea:b9:58:59:16:ff:cc:89:72:50:ab:f7:8f:40:ef:3b
The authenticity of host '**hostname** (**hostname**)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is ea:b9:58:59:16:ff:cc:89:72:50:ab:f7:8f:40:ef:3b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '**hostname**' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: could not open key file '/.ssh/id_rsa': Invalid argument
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: could not open key file '/.ssh/id_dsa': Invalid argument
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: could not open key file '/.ssh/id_ecdsa': Invalid argument
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Not sure it will make any positive difference in this case, but it looks like you're running on a (Windows?) machine with unset `$HOME` variable, since the search path for the keys in `/` seems somewhat odd.

Comment: I'm running on a Chromebook at the moment which may be why the trace looks a bit funny, but the machine in question is a Mac (which I don't have access to for the next few hours).  I sent this question to a friend and he said I may need to mention the public key that was added to authorized_hosts on the server machine.  I was able to find that, now I just need to figure out how to use it, or if that's even a problem that could exist...

Comment: When the instance was created the sysadmin asked for a public key from me, which I assume he put into authorized_keys.  I still have that key file, but have no idea how - or even if I need - to use it.  The private key is definitely correct and I specify with "-i <keyfile>" to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Whould you join the exact command you are trying?

And the output of ls $HOME/.ssh ?

If you read carefully through the stacktrace it looks like SSH does not find any key at the default locations. The server replies that you did not provide the right key, the debug output tells me that you did not provide any key.

So find out first where you private key is on your client computer :)

Then move it to .ssh/id_rsa or do `ssh -i <key_location> ubuntu@myhost` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: "I tried ssh -i <keyname>.pem user@host" from the location that the .pem file is located with no luck.

I'm worried that the authroized_keys file on the server was modified and I no longer have the correct public key, but I'm very unfamiliar with SSH, so that may not even be a possibility.

I'm absolutely sure this is the correct .pem file, and I'm using the only username that I ever had to use.  

Is there something that could go wrong after re-imaging the client machine that owuld be causing this?

Comment: tries `ssh-agent bash` then `ssh-add <pem file>` then login

Comment: Yes, but the output you posted is not the output of the command using -i ? Please give us the debug output with the -i option.